# How to implement CMMI RSKM SP 1.1 Determine Risk Sources and Categories in TFS?

Tags: tfs, cmmi

TFS's CMMI for Process Improvement process template has a Word template called RiskCategoriesandSources.dot for registering risk sources and categories but there aren't any fields in the Risk Work Item Template for defining Source and Category.

How are the risks sources and categories used to inform the Risk work item if at all?

Answer (score 3):

Try this - [A Comprehensive Survey or Risk Sources and Categories](http://www.dtic.mil/ndia/2004cmmi/CMMIT2WedPM/1142WarrenScheinin.pdf).

Comment: Hi Trevor, could you please provide a summary in your answer of the main ideas included in the link? If the link were to ever break, the answer would be useless to future visitors. But with a summary, it would continue to provide some value for years to come, even if the link breaks. (Normally, I would try an [edit] myself, but I'm not 100% sure what you meant to highlight.)  Good luck! :)